# Wrapper directive and class duplication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just want to make a directive to wrap an element. I've tried with this one:

```
.directive('wrap', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: 'element',
    template: '<div class="wrapper" ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

But when I use it:

```
<a class="my-class" wrap>Hello</a>
```

I'm getting `my-class` duplicated:

```
<div class="my-class wrapper" ng-transclude="" wrap="">
  <a class="my-class ng-scope" wrap="">Hello</a>
</div>
```

What I want is just that but without `my-class` in the wrapper div:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-transclude="" wrap="">
  <a class="my-class ng-scope" wrap="">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You ca do it with tranclude: true:

```
app.directive('wrap', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="wrapper" ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

html:

```
<div wrap><a class="my-class">Hello</a></div>
```

or (if you use restrict:'E'):

```
<wrap><a class="my-class">Hello</a></wrap>
```

output:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-transclude="" wrap="">
    <a class="my-class ng-scope">Hello</a>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bxeeo4lytcicoXE65MU9?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that's in fact the way I'm using to have it work. I'm just curious about getting the same result with something like `<a class="my-class" wrap>Hello</a>` without explicitly "wrapping" it.